# What does "who deserves it" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm confused with the phrase "who deserves it" in this passage.

It says "who" but the passage seems to be talking about how anorexia should be treated/represented, and whether it should be given attention or visibility at all. I'm confused why the author wrote "who" here, rather than "whether it deserves representation at all" or something like that. Could someone explain this to me? Thank you.

> Pro-ana spaces and influencers raise crucial questions about
> representation, and **who deserves it**. Should we treat anorexia like
> depression and anxiety, an inseparable aspect of character that merits
> sensitive treatments by scriptwriters and reality show producers? Or
> is naming anorexia, or even showing it without naming it, encouraging
> the slender ideal? But meditations on the how thinness and anorexia
> are depicted in entertainment and media are dwarfed by online
> propagation of thinspiration content and unrelenting, unending stream
> of photoshopped bodies.

Comment: 'who' refers to the people who deserve representation ('it').

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but the later part of the passage doesn't seem to be talking about **who**, among 
 people with anorexia, deserves representation. Rather, it seems to be talking about **whether or not** anorexia deserves representation at all.

Comment: It is poorly written. It mentions _crucial questions about representation_, and also, as an addendum to that, the matter of _who deserves that representation_, That added item is itself should probably be considered one of the 'crucial questions'. Issue-centred blogs are not always good sources of edited,  clear and coherent English.

Comment: From the context, representation is that of women bodies in the media (mostly thin, even skinny in Pro-ana spaces) and "who" refers to the models of femininity that shall be featured.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, and the two specific examples of these crucial questions are presented in the later part of the passage. (1. Should we treat anorexia like depression? 2. is naming anorexia... encouraging the slender ideal?) And you'd expect each example to be talking about "representation" and "who deserves it" respectively, given how the author mentions them at the beginning of the passage, but no, both are about representation but none of them seem to talk about "who deserves it". Then why the author mentioned "who deserves it"? That's what I'm confused about here. Hope this makes sense

Comment: You are confused because the writer is unable to organise their ideas coherently. Perhaps it was written in haste by someone who is not a professional writer. It is not the purpose of this site to unravel such puzzles.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I see. So it might just be a slip-up on the writer's part. Thank you all for helping me out. Much appreciated.

Comment: I understand it to mean 'whether or not people with anorexia deserve representation (in the same way as people with depression)'.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree. It makes more sense to interpret it that way. Do you think it's just a mistake by the writer?

Comment: No, I don't see it as a 'mistake' - just something that, perhaps, could have been expressed more clearly.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: It seems perfectly reasonable to me. "Who deserves representation" is a general question. The issue of how anorexia is presented is a more specific elaboration of a general point, of whether people with anorexia deserve representation, to what extent, and in what way. That's how people are usually told to write paragraphs: start with something general, and then elaborate. Most people would be aware that anorexia is a disease of people, and therefore "who" would refer to people with the disease.

Comment: @StuartF "Who deserves representation" sounds to me like a matter of deciding who should be represented as a person with anorexia and who shouldn't, while "whether people with anorexia deserve representation" sounds like a matter of whether they, as a whole, should be represented in the first place. So I feel like these two phrases are a bit different from each other in meaning.

Comment: @StuartF Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I think it is not clear whether the writer is considering the representation in the media of anorexia and of people who suffer from it on the one hand, and on the other, the issue of representation of body types, where (I expect) it is considered that only certain shapes (slim women, muscular men, etc) are favoured. I lean towards the latter interpretation. Perhaps I should read the whole piece. However such a matter goes beyond the remit of this site.

Comment: _"Who deserves representation" sounds to me like a matter of deciding who should be represented as a person with anorexia and who shouldn't._  But previously you said you agreed with my interpretation, which was _whether or not people with anorexia deserve representation as much as people with depression or anxiety do_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you should read the whole piece and google the influencers/Youtubers' names. The images of these women with severely undernourished bodies are horrifying. The author of the piece is also asking whether these young women should be allowed to post their images and thoughts on social media. The potential harm caused is probably greater than their "right" to be seen and heard, and to represent the hundreds or thousands of teenagers and adults who  follow the same rigid dietary regimes.

Comment: @KateBunting Oh! I think I was completely misunderstanding it this whole time.
I thought my interpretation was the literal meaning of the phrase, and that your interpretation was a result of you interpreting it in a way that fits the context, because the literal meaning doesn't make sense. Now I just realized your interpretation is the literal meaning of the phrase. I'm sorry. Probably I sounded like a complete idiot all along (which I am). I now understand what Stuart F meant, too.

Comment: No, you're not an idiot - the passage is poorly expressed, as has been mentioned before.

Comment: @KateBunting - I am now in two minds. Maybe the writer was?

Comment: @noolodig - you are very far from being an idiot. They are the people who do not ask questions, or think about what they are reading online.

Answer (score 4):

> Pro-ana spaces and influencers raise crucial questions about representation, and **who** deserves **it**.

The word **"it"** refers to the word **"representation"**.The word **"who"** refers to **"the people who deserve representation"**.

> Pro-ana spaces and influencers raise crucial questions about representation, and who deserves **representation**.